# Set width of webcam is not working

Tags: opencv, webcam

I have a webcam ( camlife HD 5000 )

when i connect it with opencv and write this code

```
VideoCapture camera;
camera.open(0);
if(!camera.isOpened()){cout<<"Error";return 0;}

cout<<camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720.0);
cout<<camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280.0);

namedWindow("ramzy",CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);

while(true){
    Mat frame;
    camera>>frame;
   // resize(frame,frame,Size(1280,720));
    if(!frame.data){cout<<"ERROR";return 0;}
    imshow("ramzy",frame);
     imwrite("Sadad.jpg",frame);
    char c=waitKey(10);
    cout<<frame.cols<<endl;
    if(c==27){break;}
}
```

it returns 1 from camera.set but the width and height remains 640*480.

I am using opencv 2.4.10 , i also tried this on opencv 2.3.1 but both failed

I  saw many solutions but all of them failed with me , What shall i do now ??

Comment: Naive question: Does your cam supports this resolution?

Comment: yes it supports this resolution

Comment: What platform are you developing on?  The logic that runs under the hood is very different for video device configuration if you're running (for example) on Linux vs. Windows.

Comment: i am developing on windows

Comment: Just to rule out a simple, easy-to-make mistake, have you confirmed that device 0 is actually your LifeCam HD 5000 webcam?  On many laptops, that's the integrated webcam.  If you're not sure, try this: `camera.open(1)`

Comment: yea actually this time i was trying to access my internal webcam of the laptop but i used camera.open(1) to access lifecam and still the same results :/

Comment: I ran your code on my Windows machine, using my Logitech C310 HD webcam which also supports 1280x720 resolution.  I did not experience the problem you're describing, although I did need to alter the `if(!frame.data)` logic since you can't necessarily expect that the first few frames will be grabbed immediately after initialization.